# C# Merging the results from SQL queries in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Good day,

What I'm working on right now, is I have a foreach loop that i going trough a file with a list of servers. Every time it goes trough it queries a different server from a list provided from a text file. The results are displayed in a datagridview. But right now every time it is querying a new server, it overwrites the data that is already in the datagridview. I tried to merge the datatable but its not working. Any Idea?

```
 try
            {
                String select = "select @@servername as Servername, @@servicename as Instance,SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as Version, SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel') as Level, SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') as Edition";
                cnn.Open();
                // MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
                MessageBox.Show("Connection established");



                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, cnn);

                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                dataGridView.DataSource = table;
                table.Merge(table);


                cnn.Close();


                //PaintRows();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! " + ex);
            }
```

Comment: where is the code that you have stated you are using in a loop.. is this relevant to what you have posted below.also what is this `table.Merge(table)` when you call the Fill method is `table being populated..? if so then where is the other table that you want to merge with the existing `table` that of which you have just filled..? ` `MessageBox.Show("Connection established");` unnecessary if you would use the debugger you would know whether it would connect or not btw.. Show all relevant code..

Comment: You are creating a new `DataTable` each time.  You need to declare the `DataTable` outside of your loop, then the line `dataAdapter.Fill(table);` will append the results to the table each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to append to your table, but you're creating a new one in every loop iteration.

What I'd do is: Create a method that takes the target table variable (so it is the same in every call).

Outline of this:

```
**** This code is somewhere to fill the table ****
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach (line in file)
{
    // Create connection to new server
    cnn = ...;

    // Append the results to the existing table
    AppendSqlResults(table, cnn);
}

// Set the source AFTER collecting all the data
dataGridView.DataSource = table;

**** This method appends the data to the table ****
public void AppendSqlResults(DataTable table, SqlConnection cnn)
{ 
    cnn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, cnn);

    SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    dataAdapter.Fill(table);
    cnn.Close();
}
```